# fmtcount out of date?

Tags: fmtcount

I'm new in latex and need some help. I've got a project with some extra packages manually stored in a folder. Compiler gets them via makefile.

After compilation I get extra first page with text:

```
spanish[2016/01/12] portuges[2016/01/12] french[2017/06/15]fc@gl@let fc@gl@def KV@fcfrench@france@defaultKV@fc@@do@plural@mark fc@@nbrstr@Fpreamble fc@@pot@longscalefrench fc@@pot@shortscalefrench
fc@@pot@recursivefrench fc@muladdfrench fc@lthundredstringfrench fc@ltthousandstringfrench
@@numberstringfrench @@ordinalstringfrench german[2016/01/12]germanb
```

It seems that it's a packet called `fmtcount` and it causes this page to appear. What does that mean and how to disable it?

Error logs are like these (also errors in german, portugese and french .def files):

```
\ProvidesFCLanguage Undefined control sequence. fc-spanish.def     
#54 \ProvidesFCLanguage{spanish}[2016/01/12]%
```

Here's my project:

File ***pre.tex***

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{hitec}

\usepackage{cmap}         

\usepackage[a4paper,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,unicode]{hyperref}


\usepackage{mathtext}                
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{indentfirst}      

\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{latexsym}     

\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[centerlast]{caption}  
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{register}       
\usepackage{timing} 
\usepackage{longtable}      
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}   

\usepackage{bm}

\sloppy     

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makecaption}[2]{
  \vspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
  \sbox{\@tempboxa}{#1. #2}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
  #1. #2\par
  \else
  \global\@minipagefalse
  \hbox to \hsize {\hfil #1. #2\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vspace{\belowcaptionskip}}
\makeatother
```

File ***Main_test.tex***

```
%% INCLUDE DIRECTORY
\makeatletter 
\def\input@path{{../tex/}} 
\makeatother 

\input{pre.tex}

\title{My title}
\author{Author}
\company{Company}
\confidential{}
\date{\today~(\currenttime)}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `datetime` package automatically loads `fmtcount`. If you replace `\usepackage{datetime}` with `\usepackage[regional]{datetime2}` the `fmtcount` package won't be needed. (You'll need the appropriate language modules, such as [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english).)

Comment: No package - no problem. Seems that it worked.

Comment: (If you do need `fmtcount` for some reason, start with a minimal `\listfiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fmtcount}\begin{document}Test.\end{document}` and report any errors and version details from that.)